# Cant Login to Chat for SU

Tags: support, chat

I can log in to Super User but not the chat site.  It sit's at "Logging you in to the Stack Exchange chat..." and does nothing.  Additionally, I can see the chat room and view it, but it say's I'm not logged in and to login.  Which of course doesn't work.  If I login at the SE level, it still doesn't work.  It'd be nice if it'd give me an error message...

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a workaround. I clicked the diagnostics link. Then at the bottom of that page was a "login using SE" link. I clicked on that and it worked.